# Listing files of particular pattern in bash

Tags: bash, shell, cmd

I have a situation in which i have to list file which is of the type as

**databaseName.schemaName@1234sdf2323.lock** where _Database_Name and _target_schema_name 
_lockFolder  are variables

@ is a token then it is followed by the random alphanumeric number and the same is end with .lock .

I have acheived this in batch file through the code as

```
FOR /R %_lockFolder% %%F in (%_Database_Name%.%_target_schema_name%@*.lock) do (
    for /f "tokens=1*  delims=@  " %%G IN ("%%~nF") DO ( 
        SET _no=%%H 
        )
)
```

but when i am changing it into bash enviorment so that it can run on unix enviorment

```
for entry in "${_lockFolder}"/*
do
  echo ENTRY "$entry"

name='${_lockFolder}/${_Database_Name}.${_target_schema_name}@*.lock'

ls -l $name > "${lockFolder}"

if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
then
     echo "Do your work here"
else
     echo "No files are there for the given pattern"
fi  


#   exit 21 

done
```

It is not able to recognize the pattern . The files are present in the folder which i have specified

Comment: The purpose of your new code seems conflicting with your original code. Shouldn't you be populating the `.lock` files in `${_Database_Name}.${_target_schema_name}`?

Comment: no the purpose is same the ${_Database_Name}.${_target_schema_name}@some_random_number.lock file to be found in the ${lockFolder}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simple write a for loop like,

```
for file in `find ${lockdir} -name "^${_lockFolder}/${_Database_Name}.${_target_schema_name}@*.lock$"`
do 
echo $file 
:
:
your job

done
```

example,

```
[root@giam20 unix]# ls
checksumupdator.sh                 GIAMMEFProcessor.sh                         GIAMRoleExtractor.sh
GIAMAccountExtractor.sh            GIAMMetaDataLoader.sh                       GIAMRoleLoader.sh
GIAMAccountLoader.sh               GIAMOOPControlledAttrExtractor.sh           GIAMRoleMappingLoader.sh
GIAMAccountTransferLoader.sh       GIAMOOPControlledAttrsLoader.sh             
 [root@giam20 unix]# find . -name "GIAM*.sh"
        ./GIAMAccountTransferLoader.sh
        ./GIAMIntermediateCodeUpgrader.sh
        ./GIAMServiceUpdator.sh
        ./GIAMOOPControlledAttrsUpdator.sh
        ./GIAMRoleUpdator.sh
        ./GIAMProvisioningPolicyExtractor.sh
        ./GIAMCompExemptionExtractor.sh
        ./GIAMApprovalNotificationLoader.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In Unix shell scripting, variable references are not resolved in a string that is enclosed in single quotes. Therefore, in this line

```
name='${_lockFolder}/${_Database_Name}.${_target_schema_name}@*.lock'
```

the value will be stored into `name` literally, including all the `${name}` references. It is no surprise then that the pattern is not matched later.

So, just change the single quotes to double quotes:

```
name="${_lockFolder}/${_Database_Name}.${_target_schema_name}@*.lock"
```

Comment: but same is not working after changing as described by your answer

Comment: Have you tried echoing `$name` in the loop so that you could see what value it gets?